# B&R Automation Studio: Toolbox not showing

Tags: automation, plc, br-automation-studio

I want to import a program from the toolbox, but the toolbox on the right of Automation Studio is gone. I can't find it anywhere. How do I enable it?

[image: Toolbox position in red, where it is supposed to be]

Answer (score 2):

I would say you are doing everything right and the Toolbox pane is there - I can see it (there is a small grey dot there).

[image]

You just need to drag the pane separator.

Answer (score 2):

When disaster strikes you always have the capability of restoring the default window layout from Window -> Reset Window Layout

[Window -> Reset Window Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/by9x1.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try the right click on the project name and select "Add object.." the toolbox menu will be shown. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZiZdD.jpg)